# Navbar Elements Not showing

Tags: javascript, html

I have been on a project to build a website to help students with revision.
I decided to make use of a cool navbar I found online in the website as I am not much of a professional myself. However, the navbar elements (the navbar is a unordered list which has been styled) don't show when i put any sort of background picture in the 'top' div. When it doesn't have a background picture (like in the fiddle) it is impossible to use the navbar properly.

This is the navbar I used:
http://cssmenumaker.com/menu/responsive-flat-menu#

I have fiddled about the position on the cssmenu div, tried putting it in the nav id and classes (both have styles set in the CSS).

Here is the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/jgs5uqxr/

It says I need to attach some code with the fiddle so here is the formating of my navbar

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
   <ul>
      <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
      <li class='active'><a href='#'>Products</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a href='#'>Product 1</a>
               <ul>
                  <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                  <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href='#'>Product 2</a>
               <ul>
                  <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                  <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I would have expected my chnages to make a working multi-level navbar which I can work with so I can add links to the educational material for students.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to add a background image to the menu?
because in the fiddle it works perfectly just that it doesnt has any background image

Comment: @ivan in the fiddle, when you open the navbar it is very hard to access the third level, and yes I am wanting to add a background. Thanks for the quick help.

Comment: Add background-image CSS style with image url

Comment: Ah you mean that you want to click anywhere on the bar for it to expand the menu instead of having to click on the plus/minus sign?

Comment: @JayGanesan I ahve done that and it simply stops the 2nd level elements of the navbar showing.

Comment: @ivan it would usually open on hover or on smaller devices on click. So I would like to be able to fully open the navbar instead of having only having one level open. (the product 1 and product 2 open up further).

Comment: This is the navbar I used: http://cssmenumaker.com/menu/responsive-flat-menu#

Comment: @JeffBanks just edited your fiddle, made the buttons to expand bigger and added a background image to the first level of the menu.
https://jsfiddle.net/1hozfxg4/2/

Comment: Note that you will have to use a specific sized image for it to show properly

Comment: Also the menu expanding whole isnt a very good practice but you can accomplish it with code, unfortunately i dont have much time left on my hands so if you havent accomplished this later i might be able to give a hand with that.

Comment: @ivan If you don't mind, could you add it to a new fiddle so I can study the changes so I can learn from it. Thanks

Comment: Oh, i can make a new fiddle, and also i wouldnt mind explaining the changes i did, they werent many.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1hozfxg4/5/
thats the fiddle with the changes i made.

Comment: @ivan What size picture should I add? Alos, I don't see any picture or any difference from the fiddle, maybe it'll work in my ide?

Comment: @JeffBanks
Huh, thats odd, this is how it looks for me:
https://imgur.com/ZyuzqtO
(probably not so noticeable since its a black image)

Comment: @ivan Oh, thats because your browser size is too small, when enlargened it like this: http://prntscr.com/mfe6jd. This is on my screen and product 1 and 2 won't open any further as the menu closes anytime I go near them.

Comment: Ah i now see what you mean, ill try to figure it out